# Scraping Data with Beautiful Soup Issues

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on scraping the countries of astronauts from this website: https://www.supercluster.com/astronauts?ascending=false&limit=72&list=true&sort=launch%20order.  I am using BeautifulSoup to perform this task, but I'm having some issues.  Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

data = []

url = 'https://www.supercluster.com/astronauts?ascending=false&limit=72&list=true&sort=launch%20order'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all('div', class_ ='astronaut_index__content container--xl mxa f fr fw aifs pl15 pr15 pt0')

for item in tags:
    name = item.select_one('bau astronaut_cell__title bold mr05')
    country = item.select_one('mouseover__contents rel py05 px075 bau caps small ac').get_text(strip = True)
    data.append([name,country])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

df is returning an empty list.  Not sure what is going on.  When I take the code out of the for loop, it can't seem to find the select_one function.  Function should be coming from bs4 - not sure why that's not working.  Also, is there a repeatable pattern for web scraping that I'm missing?  Seems like it's a different beast every time I try to tackle these kinds of problems.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url's data is generated dynamically by javascript and Beautifulsoup can't grab dynamic data.So, You can use automation tool something like selenium with Beautifulsoup.Here I apply selenium with Beautifulsoup.Please just run the code.

**Script:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time


data = []

url = 'https://www.supercluster.com/astronauts?ascending=false&limit=300&list=true&sort=launch%20order'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.close()
tags = soup.select('.astronaut_cell.x')

for item in tags:
    name = item.select_one('.bau.astronaut_cell__title.bold.mr05').get_text()
    #print(name.text)
    country = item.select_one('.mouseover__contents.rel.py05.px075.bau.caps.small.ac')
    if country:
        country=country.get_text()
    #print(country)
    
    data.append([name, country])



cols=['name','country']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
name                   country
0       Bess, Cameron  United States of America
1          Bess, Lane  United States of America
2          Dick, Evan  United States of America
3       Taylor, Dylan  United States of America
4    Strahan, Michael  United States of America
..                ...                       ...
295     Jones, Thomas  United States of America
296      Sega, Ronald  United States of America
297     Usachov, Yury                    Russia
298   Fettman, Martin  United States of America
299       Wolf, David  United States of America

[300 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Hey @F.Hoque, this is great!  How could I adapt this to get all the names and countries in the entire dataset rather than just the first 72?

Comment: Oh! I see.  Is there a way to dynamically choose the length of the list instead of hard coding a number in the URL?

Comment: I tried load more pagination but didn't work that's why I took this technique

Comment: Last question - I just upped it to a very large number (ie: 5000) and that seemed to do the trick but it only caught the humans in space.  Is there a way to also grab the non-humans too?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure but it will work  in whole dataset that  contains the url.

Comment: I'll fiddle with that on my own - thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey another question - what should I edit to have the browser not pop up every time I load the code?  I tried switching driver.maximize_window() to driver.minimize_window() and that helps a little, but I'd rather have nothing pop up if possible.

Comment: @user2813606, driver.close(). I've updated

Comment: Thanks @F.Hoque!  This helped remove the browser after it had already opened.  Is there a way to structure this code without using driver.maximize_window()?

Comment: You can try, Hope it will work without using driver.maximize_window()

Answer (score 1):

The page is dynamically loaded using javascript, so requests can't get to it directly. The data is loaded from another address and is received in json format. You can get to it this way:

```
url = "https://supercluster-iadb.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/adb_mobile.json"
req = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(req.text)
```

Once you have it loaded, you can iterate through it and retrieve relevant information. For example:

```
for astro in data['astronauts']:
  print(astro['astroNumber'],astro['firstName'],astro['lastName'],astro['rank'])
```

Output:

```
1 Yuri Gagarin Colonel
10 Walter Schirra Captain
100 Georgi Ivanov Major General
101 Leonid Popov Major General
102 Bertalan Farkas Brigadier General
```

etc.

You can then load the output to a pandas dataframe or whatever.